# update initramfs every time rpm is installed or updated

Tags: linux-kernel, rpm, initramfs, sles, modprobe

i am working on rpm which contains kernel modules to be installed in to /lib/modules/<uname -r>/updates folder. Since the module is part of initramfs. when ever i install rpm i have to manually update initramfs with command dracut. is there a way i can update initramfs  from the rpm spec file itself. if yes, can some one help with the data or reference link. what permissions does rpm need.

Comment: Every rpm spec manual has a section about `scriptlets`. Just add a `%post` section to update the initramfs using a relevant command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
%post
if [ $1 -gt 1 ] && [ -e /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) ] && [ -e /sbin/depmod ] && [ -x %{_sbindir}/dracut ]; then
    /sbin/depmod -a "$(uname -r)"
    %{_sbindir}/dracut -f --kver "$(uname -r)"
fi
```

Comment: This worked` if [ -e /boot/vmlinuz-\$(uname -r) ] && [ -e /sbin/depmod ] && [ -x %{_bindir}/dracut ]; then
        /sbin/depmod -a "\$(uname -r)"
        %{_bindir}/dracut -f --kver "\$(uname -r)"
fi `